# How to connect vb.net connection with sybase?

Tags: vb.net, sybase

How can I connect my sybase database on different server from my vb.net ?
I want to develop an application to manipulate the server data .

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/ you could see that there are two providers for it. Choose the correct one for you

Comment: but I couldnot download the aseclient.dll file? Where can I get the file. the site you suggested have not the valid link

Comment: I would start my search from the same TAG page you have linked http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sybase/info